# Cant´t get cookie - Express

Tags: express, cookies

I created a server with express and have some get/post routes.

In the login page, I have a page that shows the form to login:

```
    app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<h1>Iniciar sesión</h1>
  <form method='post' action='/login'>
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' required />
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Contraseña' required />
    <input type='submit' value='Ingresar' />
  </form>
  <a href='/register'>Registrarse</a`);
});
```

Then I have a Post method in which I set the cookies:

```
    app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = users.filter(
    (e) => e.email === email && e.password === password
  );

  if (user.length >= 1) {
    res.cookie("userId", user.id);
    res.cookie("password", user.password);
    res.redirect("/home");
  } else {
    console.log("contraseña incorrecta");
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});
```

The problem is that when I go to this route, the user.name and user.email are undefined. In other words, I can´t acces to the cookie:

```
app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.cookies.userId;
  console.log(id); //this is undefined
  const user = users.filter((u) => u.id === id);
  //console.log(user);

  res.send(`
    <h1>Bienvenido ${user.name}</h1>
    <h4>${user.email}</h4>
    <a href='/'>Inicio</a>
  `);
});
```

Advices?

Here is the complete code:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cookieparser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

const users = [
  { id: 1, name: "Franco", email: "Franco@mail.com", password: "1234" },
  { id: 2, name: "Toni", email: "Toni@mail.com", password: "1234" },
];

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
    <h1>Bienvenidos a Henry!</h1>
    ${
      req.cookies.userId
        ? `<a href='/home'>Perfil</a>
    <form method='post' action='/logout'>
      <button>Salir</button>
    </form>
    `
        : `
    <a href='/login'>Ingresar</a>
    <a href='/register'>Registrarse</a>`
    }
  `);
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<h1>Registrarse</h1>
  <form method='post' action='/register'>
    <input name='name' placeholder='Nombre' required />
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' required />
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Contraseña' required />
    <input type='submit' value='Registrarse' />
  </form>
  <a href='/login'>Iniciar sesión</a>`);
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<h1>Iniciar sesión</h1>
  <form method='post' action='/login'>
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' required />
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Contraseña' required />
    <input type='submit' value='Ingresar' />
  </form>
  <a href='/register'>Registrarse</a`);
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = users.filter(
    (e) => e.email === email && e.password === password
  );

  if (user.length >= 1) {
    res.cookie("userId", user.id);
    res.cookie("password", user.password);
    res.redirect("/home");
  } else {
    console.log("contraseña incorrecta");
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.cookies;
  console.log(id);
  const user = users.filter((u) => u.id === id);
  //console.log(user);

  res.send(`
    <h1>Bienvenido ${user.name}</h1>
    <h4>${user.email}</h4>
    <a href='/'>Inicio</a>
  `);
});

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Listening on localhost:3000");
  }
});
```

Comment: How is the client accessing the route where you expect the cookie?  Is it just a URL typed into the browser?  Or is it a Javascript Ajax call?  If it's code, please show the client code.

Comment: URL typed into the browser

Comment: FYI, storing user's passwords in plain text on your server is certainly not recommended.  And putting a password in a cookie is not recommended either.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that this code:

```
const user = users.filter(
  (e) => e.email === email && e.password === password
);
```

produces an Array.  So, `user` is an array.

Therefore when you do this:

```
res.cookie("userId", user.id);
res.cookie("password", user.password);
```

Both `user.id` and `user.password` are ignoring the match you got in `user[0]` and are referring to non-existent properties on the `user` array object.  They will end up `undefined` and thus why `res.cookie()` is not setting a meaningful value.

You should, instead be doing this:

```
res.cookie("userId", user[0].id);
res.cookie("password", user[0].password);
```

But, please don't put a password in a user's cookie.  There should be no reason to ever do that.  Even more so when it's in plain text.  If you want to know if the previous user is logged in or not, then use a cryptographically secure token in the cookie (like something express-session uses).  Don't put their password in a cookie.